# How to stop background image from contracting on resizing

Tags: html, css

So i have a div with a background image with background size set to cover. 
Here is the div code:

```css
.imgContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 340px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 0;
  background: url('https://dummyimage.com/800x680/ccc/333');
  background-position: 50% 25%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width:650px) {
  .imgContainer {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer"></div>
```

The background shows the image completely but since i am making my site responsive, i change the div on width 650px using the @media rule.

```
@media screen and (max-width:650px){
  .imgContainer {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

When the div is enlarged, the background-image widens and don't show much content of the image. The image's content is shown completely when the width is 400px and height 340px. The problem occurs when the div's width is 100% and the image's content does not show as much as it shows when it is 400px wide. How to fix this? 
And thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried with background-size: contain; ?

Comment: Yes i have tried it

Comment: Not really clear what you want, or what the actual problem is. If you don’t want the effect of background-size contain or cover - then what else? _“when the window or device is of any width, the image should be the same”_ - so … just no specified background-size at all …?

Comment: The image's content is shown completely when the width is 400px and height 340px. The problem occurs when the div's width is 100% and the image's content does not show as much as it shows when it is 400px wide.

Comment: But that's how cover works, it resizes the image respecting aspect ratio to cover the whole div. Can you show two images of the current behaviour and the expected?

Comment: It is unclear, what you want to achieve. Could you elaborate a little bit more. Images of the state your image does show now and how you want the image to show would be very helpful

Comment: Let's make some assumptions and you should clarify, if those are true or false.
1. The image you use is 400x340 pixels big or has an aspect ratio of 400:340?
2. Above 650 pixel viewport width the image shows completely and that's how it should be?
3. At 650 pixel and below viewport width the image is the image is clipped, but should show completely?
4. Instead it should show with the same width as theimage above 650 pixel viewport width?

Comment: I'm trying to make an image upload system. User can upload any image and the div takes the image as background. When the window is resized and container's width is set to 100%, the image stretches and thus does not show much content as it showed before.

Answer (score 0):

With `background-size: cover` you're telling the browser to ensure that the image covers the entirety of the element while maintaining the image's original aspect-ratio. So it is to be expected that changing the aspect ratio of the HTML element will cut off some of the image to make this happen.

In order to make your image responsive you'll have to ensure that the aspect-ratio of your image remains the same.

One way to do this is to use something like the following:

```
@media screen and (max-width:650px) {
    .imgContainer {
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 85%;
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

This will set the padding to be 85% of the width of the element as 100 / (400/340) = 85. Assuming nothing else is in your `div` this will give it the appropriate aspect ratio for your image.

Comment: Yes this is too close to what i want to achieve but still the sides of the image are not that visible

Comment: Could you create a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your situation? That would help us see what's going on with your particular code/content.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.
Notice: It only works, if the image has an aspect ratio of 400:340 (e.g. 800 x 680, 600 x 510, etc.)
Notice: The 418 pixel in the last media query is an empirical value based on the current paddings and margin. You might need a different value.

[Here is the codepen to see in in action](https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/rRBbvL?editors=1100)

```css
.imgContainer {
  width: 400px;
  height: 340px;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 0;
  background: url("https://dummyimage.com/800x680/ccc/333");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .imgContainer {
    width: 100% !important;
    background-size: contain;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 418px) {
  .imgContainer {
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah i really loved it but still when it is set to contain, you can still see the colour on both sides. Is there a way to show only the image with width 100%

Comment: The grey background-color was only for demonstration purposes. I removed it

Comment: If you want the image to be 100% width there is no possibility of showing the full image without distortion. Either you set `backgroundsize: cover` (https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/Rdwbeb?editors=1100) or `background-size: 100% 100%` (https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/rRBbvL?editors=1100)